# Checking rainbow array(checking if array's reverse style matches with itself)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, loops

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    bool check;
    int lenght=1,height=1;
    int array[height][lenght];
    std::cin>>height;
    int a=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=height;i++){
        std::cin>>lenght;
        for(int i=0;i<=lenght;i++)
            std::cin>>array[a][i];
        if (lenght%2==0){
            int array1[height][lenght/2],array2[height][lenght/2];
            for(int i=0;i<=lenght/2;i++)
                array1[a][i]=array[a][i];
            for(int i=0;i<=lenght/2;i++)
                array2[a][i]=array[a][lenght-i-1];
            for(int i=0;i<=lenght/2;i++)
                if(array1[a][i]!=array2[a][i])
                check= false;
            a++;
        check=true;
        if(check==true)
        std::cout<<"its rainbow array ! ";
        else
        std::cout<<"you cant get any unicorn :( ";
        }
        else{
            int array1[height][lenght/2-1],array2[height][lenght/2-1];
            for(int i=0;i<lenght/2-1;i++)
                array1[a][i]=array[a][i];
            for(int i=0;i<lenght/2-1;i++)
                array2[a][i]=array[a][lenght-i-1];
            for(int i=0;i<lenght/2-1;i++)
                if(array1[a][i]!=array2[a][i])
                check= false;
            a++;
        check=true;
        if(check==true)
        std::cout<<"its rainbow array ! ";
        else
        std::cout<<"you cant get any unicorn :( ";
        }
    }

}
```

Sorry for bad English. I'm trying to check if we divide an array to half, then check if these pieces matches.
For example = 1,2,3,4,5,6==> This is not rainbow array
1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1==> This is rainbow array.
This is how program should work:

> 1=User enters an integer, that will be our height, tells us how many number lists we will test.
>   2=User enter integer how long first list will be. Then program will get inputs from user for list.
>   3=Program should separate major list to 2 minor lists.
>   4=Program copying major list's elements to 2 minor list's.

At the final stage, it compares 2 list and changing bool value to true or false. But in my situation its always true. Here is a working code that i wrote few hours ago.

```
#include <iostream>
bool checkarray(int *array,int lenght);
int main(){
    int array[9]={1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,4};
    int lenght=9;
    if(checkarray(array,lenght)==true)
        std::cout<<"its rainbow array ! ";
    else
        std::cout<<"you cant get any unicorn :( ";
}
bool checkarray(int array[],int lenght){
    if (lenght%2==0){
        int array1[lenght/2],array2[lenght/2];
        for(int i=0;i<=lenght/2;i++)
            array1[i]=array[i];
        for(int i=0;i<=lenght/2;i++)
            array2[i]=array[lenght-i-1];
        for(int i=0;i<=lenght/2;i++)
            if(array1[i]!=array2[i])
                return false;

        return true;
        }
    else{
        int array1[lenght/2-1],array2[lenght/2-1];
        for(int i=0;i<lenght/2-1;i++)
            array1[i]=array[i];
        for(int i=0;i<lenght/2-1;i++)
            array2[i]=array[lenght-i-1];
        for(int i=0;i<lenght/2-1;i++)
            if(array1[i]!=array2[i])
                return false;

        return true;
    }
    }
```

But whenever i want add user experience, it happens like first code. Help please

Comment: `int array[height][lenght];` -- This and lines that look like this are not legal C++. C++ requires arrays to use constants to denote the number of entries, not variables.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so how can i describe 2 dimensional dynamic array ? with new int ? ill try

Comment: `#include <vector>` then `std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(height, std::vector<int>(length));`

Answer (score 2):

for odd length arrays you should use length/2 instead of length/2-1. If the length is 9 then length/2-1 = 3, so you will check only the first and last 3 elements instead of 4. Actually you don't even need to handle these two cases in separate branches.

```
bool checkarray(int array[],int length){
    for(int i=0;i<length/2;i++)
      if(array[i]!=array[length-1-i])
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: oh thanks. But i think it should be like that: if lenght is odd, then (lenght-1)/2;

Comment: length is an integer value. length/2 automatically become an integer (rounded down) even if the original value was an odd number.